# Is "conventionally" as adverb used properly here: "It's not conventionally casino news, but ..."?

Tags: word-usage

It doesn't sound wrong to the ear for me. But *conventionally* is an adverb, and it should modify a verb or an adjective. In this case it is obviously the verb *is*. Can *conventionally* modify *be*? On the other hand, the noun *casino* in this case functions like an adjective, that's also why the sentence sounds ok, I think.

When I google *is conventionally*, it is always followed by an adjective.

So is this a correct use of *conventionally*?

(I read this last night having no more energy left to ask the question here, and it bothered me through the whole night.)

Comment: Not all adjectives, and to my knowledge no attributive nouns, are modifiable by 'adverbs' in this way. 'It's not the conventional/usual sort of casino news, ...'.

Comment: @Edwin: I'm not so sure. It seems to me describing something as *not conventionally X* is credible, and carries the implication *not X **as conventionally defined*** - so you might use it in a context where following text goes on to make a case for it *actually* being X (maybe by slightly ***redefining*** X). Which I think perhaps wouldn't be so appropriate if the initial assertion had baldy stated that it *wasn't* "conventional X".

Comment: @FF I'm not going to go further than the first 50 Google hits for "not conventionally", but have found only one strange (and non-relevant) usage (other than the adverbial and the adjective-modifier usages). No premodifier-of-attributive-noun usages. My 3-year-old son's 'very steam, that one' on being scared by a miniature locomotive never made the lists.

Comment: What is the source of the sentence?

Comment: I encountered it on one blog/newsletter site. I don't think there is anything more there that can add to this question discussion here.

Answer (score 0):

Look at these examples:

**It's not an ordinary book.**

**It's not ordinarily a book.**

They have very different meanings.
I think you wanted the adjective rather than the adverb.